# Connect Otree Project to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, otree

I'm trying to connect my Otree project to MySQL database, but whatever I do it doesn't replace the default database (which is SQLite) with MySQL. When I run the command `otree runprodserver 80` and try to access `localhost:80` I get the following message:

> Your database is not ready. Try running 'otree resetdb'. (Missing
>   tables for otree.FailedSessionCreation, otree.ChatMessage,
>   sessions.Session, and 15 other models).

(obviously running 'otree resetdb' does not solve the problem.)

I added the following lines to `settings.py` :

```
environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'mysql://localhost:3306'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'DBNAME',
        'USER': 'DBUSER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DBPASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

but it still doesn't work.
Any ideas what can I do to solve the problem?
Thanks.